# How to make conversions from varchar to datetime deterministic?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, user-defined-functions, deterministic

In the tradition of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309492/user-defined-functions-sql-server-2005-flagged-incorrectly-as-non-deterministic) and in light of [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178091(SQL.90).aspx), how does one make this function deterministic:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [udf_DateTimeFromDataDtID]
(
    @DATA_DT_ID int -- In form YYYYMMDD
)
RETURNS datetime
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar, @DATA_DT_ID))
END
```

Or this one (because of the string/date literals - and yes, I've also tried '1900-01-01'):

```
ALTER FUNCTION udf_CappedDate
(
    @DateTimeIn datetime
)
RETURNS datetime
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
    IF @DateTimeIn < '1/1/1900'
        RETURN '1/1/1900'
    ELSE IF @DateTimeIn > '1/1/2100'
        RETURN '1/1/2100'

    RETURN @DateTimeIn
END
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

BOL says that `CONVERT` *is* deterministic with datetimes if the *style* parameter is specified.  So if you change the first UDF to:

```
RETURN CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar, @DATA_DT_ID), 112)
```

Then it *should* be deterministic, if I understand the docs correctly.

Presumably, the same trick could be used in your second UDF:

```
IF @DateTimeIn < CONVERT(datetime, '1/1/1900', 101)
    RETURN CONVERT(datetime, '1/1/1900', 101)
```

I ***really*** wish there were a way to specify datetime literals in T-SQL.

**EDIT**:

As pointed out by Arvo in the comments (**thank you**, Arvo), the ODBC timestamp literal format can be used (even when using OLE DB) so the second function above could be better written as:

```
IF @DateTimeIn < {d '1900-01-01'}
    RETURN {d '1900-01-01'}
...etc.
```

and the conversion to datetime is done at compile time instead of execution time.  Note that the format of the date has to be very specific (see [Arvo's link to the datetime data type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx)):

> d    yyyy-mm-dd
>    t    hh:mm:ss[.fff]
>   ts    yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fff]

Comment: I only ever used the style when converting TO varchar - the documentation is kind of ambiguous, but I've tried it and it clearly works.

Comment: @P Daddy, Amen on the datetime literals.

Comment: About datetime literals - can't you use ODBC timestamp format like { d '1990-10-02' }? From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx:
Applications that use the ADO, OLE DB, and ODBC-based APIs can use this ODBC timestamp format to represent dates and times.

Answer (score 6):

From the articles you linked:

> To be deterministic, the style parameter must be a constant. Additionally, styles less than or equal to 100 are nondeterministic, except for styles 20 and 21. Styles greater than 100 are deterministic, except for styles 106, 107, 109 and 113.

You need to use a style parameter in your conversions to datetime.

For example:

```
CONVERT(datetime, '2008-01-01', 121)
```

Except don't use 121...

Comment: So no literal dates as strings in UDFs without being CONVERTed?

Comment: If strings get converted to dates implicitly, then those conversions lack "constant" styles and will make the function nondeterministic.